# How to sync between multiple magento sites keeping one as master?

Tags: magento-1.9, multidomain

I have two child magento websites and one master website, Now I would like to synchronize child sites when something happens to master, 
For example: When a product is added or a price change - sync to other two child websites. (i.e.) All/Custom admin activities are synchronized between Master and child magento websites.

Note: These Magento stores are not configured like Multi-stores and these are installed separately on different domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are ***not using Multi-stores functionally*** that it become ***too different  to track each of event of one store*** and then ***transfer to master website.***

Suppose,You will  try to  like `soap api,rest api, Event/observer and other customization`.

Then it would create ***hug perform issue between two website*** as every time,data will synchronize between  site.

In my point view,it is ***not possible to track each website***  event for each times.

So you cannot do a ***complete synchronize child sites with master***.

My suggest to use multi store

Comment: Hello Amit, I would like to go with multistore, however If the two child site has some individual functionality or may be different from one another, then shall I use each of them as separate theme package and configure them based on that.. I just thought of this.. will this work ?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, you need your master to have a catalog json/xml output then compare the update time (foreach) product (on master) with the data from the child sites and only save/update child site data if update time is different.

What you need
- PHP code to read each item in json/xml
- If ID matches, compare update time
- If master update time newer, update child product
- CRON job pointing to PHP file

If done this in the past with an external json API to update my magento collection data

Comment: Here is an API i am working on https://github.com/SeakEcommerce/Sync2Mage

Comment: Will this sync automatically when the changes were made?

Comment: no its just a work in progress project at the moment and I have to update the code, but once I have you can access product list in json or xml. Will let you know once I update the repo.